# From where to start?

Tags: command-line

I would like to ask about where to start learning Linux OS.
I not asking aboout how to install it, or how to use the openoffice, or Chromium explorer. I would like to have control of my computer in every single issue using the Terminal commands. Is there a recommended roadmap?

I guess that first I will need to know how is the architecture, kernel, layers etc, and then learn about commands in console, programing scripts, and so on...

Please, give me an advice and if you can, an internet source of each item recommended by you.

Comment: Try Linux.org and Linux.com. These two sites contain many articles and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for a UNIX-like guide to be independent with the console (this question is better do be done in https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Anyways, one of the things that my teachers told me to start with was [Unix for Poets](http://www.lsi.upc.edu/~padro/Unixforpoets.pdf). Also you can read about [Unix directory structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_directory_structure) and basic commands for terminal, obviously (for example [this](http://www.maketecheasier.com/basic-bash-command-for-new-linux-users/2008/01/22)). If you want to know more about Linux world, you have an entire documentation about GNU/Linux in http://www.tldp.org/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn about a particular terminal command is by reading its manual page, available via `man command-name`.

To figure out which commands you want to learn about, run `apropos topic-keyword` to list relevant commands.

For example, let's say you wanted to know how to reboot the system from the command line. You could run `apropos reboot` to list several commands that relate to rebooting in some way (my system finds 9 of them), then run `man reboot` to learn the details of the `reboot` command.